# Singleton component cannot depend on scoped components

Tags: android, dagger-2

While working on *Android* application using *Dagger2* for dependency injects while defining *Dagger* component I'm getting this error

```
Error:(13, 1) error: This @Singleton component cannot depend on scoped components:
@Singleton com.eaxample.app.DaggerAndroid.networkhandler.WebserviceComponent
```

My code of component is here:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {WebserviceModule.class}, dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class})
public interface WebserviceComponent {
      WebserviceHelper providesWebserviceHelper();
}
```

Code of componeent in which I'm getting error is:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RemoteDataModule.class}, dependencies = {WebserviceComponent.class})
public interface RemoteDataSourceComponent {
       RemoteDataSource providesRemoteDataSource();
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how to resolve this?

Comment: `RemoteDataSourceComponent` should have [custom scope](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/).

Answer (score 19):

While dmitriyzaitsev's answer explains why you get the error, here's how you can solve it:

1. Define your own scope (it will actually also behave like a Singleton scope). E.g. a file called `RemoteDataScope.java`:

   ```
   @Scope
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface RemoteDataScope {
   }
   ```
2. Use the new scope, e.g. `@RemoteDataScope` instead of `@Singleton` in your `RemoteDataSourceComponent`:

   ```
   @RemoteDataScope
   @Component(modules = {RemoteDataModule.class}, dependencies = {WebserviceComponent.class})
   public interface RemoteDataSourceComponent {
          RemoteDataSource providesRemoteDataSource();
   }
   ```

Comment: I needed to use `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)` in Kotlin instead.

Answer (score 18):

`WebserviceComponent` and `RemoteDataSourceComponent` cannot have the same scope. In dagger 2, scopes define something like lifecycle and `@Singleton` is the widest. Therefore if `RemoteDataSourceComponent` depends on `WebserviceComponent`, this means that the `WebserviceComponent` could live longer.

Comment: When component with scopeA depends on component with scopeB then will scopeB be live until all objects of scopeA are live & vice versa is not true?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (without defining extra scopes) is to separate two components with a "regular" (unannotated) interface.

In your case that'd be, say `WebService`:

```
public interface WebService {
    WebserviceHelper providesWebserviceHelper();
}
```

Make `WebserviceComponent` extend `WebService`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {WebserviceModule.class}, dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class})
public interface WebserviceComponent extends WebService {
    // empty body now
}
```

Replace `WebserviceComponent` with `WebService` for `RemoteDataSourceComponent` dependencies:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RemoteDataModule.class}, dependencies = {WebService.class})
public interface RemoteDataSourceComponent {
    RemoteDataSource providesRemoteDataSource();
}
```