# Dagger issues after upgrading from Android Studio 3.0.1 to 4.0.1 and Dagger 2.9 -> 2.25.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger-2

I’ve been working on upgrading our Android project from Android Studio 3.0.1 to 4.0.1, and as part of that, I have upgraded the following:

Build Tools Version 26.0.2 -> 30.0.2

Compile SDK Version 25 -> 28

Kotlin version 1.2.71 -> 1.4.10

Gradle version 3.1.0 -> 4.0.1

Android Support v7 -> androidx 1.0.0

Dagger 2.9 -> 2.28.3

Retrofit 2.2.0 -> 2.9.0

Okhttp 3.7.0 -> 4.9.0

I am now running into an issue where I am getting an error saying the following:

```
@dagger.Component(dependencies = {org.bbb.ccc.app.application.AppComponent.class}, modules = {org.bbb.ccc.app.ddd.yyy.zzz.class})
^
      @Singleton org.bbb.ccc.app.application.AppComponent/Users/xxx/aaa_android/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/eee/org/xxx/ddd/app/application/AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends error.NonExistentClass>,javax.inject.Provider<org.bbb.ccc.app.dagger.fragment.FragmentComponentBuilder<?,?>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

So far, as part of this migration, I have moved several classes from being a Singleton to their own scope, as discussed in [Singleton component cannot depend on scoped components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387631/singleton-component-cannot-depend-on-scoped-components)

I have also tried to follow the information here: http://frogermcs.github.io/activities-multibinding-in-dagger-2/ as well as a few other things, and I have not yet been able to get the build to compile with AS4. This project compiled in 3.0.1 before upgrading.

---

Onto code now:
App.kt:

```
 package org.bbb.ccc.app.application

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.StrictMode
import android.util.Log
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric
import io.realm.Realm
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration
import org.bbb.ccc.app.dagger.activity.ActivityComponentBuilder
import org.bbb.ccc.app.dagger.activity.HasActivitySubcomponentBuilders
import org.bbb.ccc.app.data.migration.KäsefüßeRealmMigration
import org.bbb.ccc.app.data.repository.RealmDatabase
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.logouttimer.LogoutTimerService
import javax.inject.Inject


/**
 * Application Class (Debug Version)
 * @desc - Instantiate a Base class for all Android Activities and Services.  Also creates global
 * objects for Realm, Dagger, Analytics, Memory Management, etc.
 */
open class App : Application(), HasActivitySubcomponentBuilders {
    companion object {
        var context: Context? = null
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityComponentBuilders: MutableMap<Class<out Activity?>?, @JvmSuppressWildcards ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>?>

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this

        // Set Crashlytics for Firebase
        Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())

        createRealm("KäsefüßeDebug.Realm", 4L)

        appComponent = createAppComponent()
        appComponent.inject(this)
        try{
            Intent(this, LogoutTimerService::class.java).also { intent ->
                startService(intent)
            }
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException){
            Log.d("Käsefüße", e.toString())
        }


        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build())

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build())
    }

    override fun onTerminate() {
        LogoutTimerService.sharedInstance.cancelTimer()
        Intent(this, LogoutTimerService::class.java).also { intent ->
            stopService(intent)
        }

        super.onTerminate()
    }

    protected open fun createAppComponent() : AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this))
                .apiModule(ApiModule())
                .dbModule(DbModule())
                .build()
    }

    protected open fun createRealm(realmName: String, realmVersion: Long) {
        Realm.init(this)

        RealmDatabase.realmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(realmName)
                .schemaVersion(realmVersion)
                .migration(KäsefüßeRealmMigration())
                .build()
    }

    override fun getBuilder(activityClass: Class<out Activity?>?): ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>? {
        return activityComponentBuilders[activityClass]
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt:

```
package org.bbb.ccc.app.application

import android.content.Context
import dagger.Component
import org.bbb.ccc.app.vol.ComplimenteuseService
import org.bbb.ccc.app.dagger.activity.ActivityBindingModule
import org.bbb.ccc.app.data.preference.PreferenceFactory
import org.bbb.ccc.app.Fromage.FromageService
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.Ananas.AnanasActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.pommeDuTerre.PommeDuTerreActivity
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, ActivityBindingModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(app: App)

    fun inject(FromageService: FromageService)

    fun inject(complimenteuseService: ComplimenteuseService)

    fun context() : Context

    fun preferenceFactory() : PreferenceFactory

    fun inject(ananasActivity: AnanasActivity)

    fun inject(pommeDuTerreActivity: PommeDuTerreActivity)
}
```

AppModule.kt:

```
package org.bbb.ccc.app.application

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import com.google.gson.Gson
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import io.reactivex.Scheduler
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import org.bbb.ccc.app.bluetooth.BTUtils
import org.bbb.ccc.app.data.preference.PreferenceFactory
import org.bbb.ccc.app.domain.model.Profile
import org.bbb.ccc.app.domain.network.KäsefüßeAPI
import org.bbb.ccc.app.domain.repository.ComplimenteuseRepository
import org.bbb.ccc.app.domain.repository.TrainRepository
import org.bbb.ccc.app.domain.repository.UserRepository
import org.bbb.ccc.app.login.interactor.ProfileInteractor
import org.bbb.ccc.app.login.interactor.ProfileManager
import org.bbb.ccc.app.presentation.interactor.SchedulerProvider
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.android.DeviceNameGenerator
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.android.HasConnection
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.connectionstate.ConnectionBroadCastReceiverRegistry
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.connectionstate.ConnectionNotifier
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.connectionstate.OkHttpPingService
import org.bbb.ccc.app.utils.extensions.hasInternetConnection
import javax.inject.Singleton

/**
 * App Module - Dagger.
 */
@Module(includes = [ApiModule::class, DbModule::class])
class AppModule(private val application: App) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun app(): App = application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun sharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences =
            application.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun applicationContext() : Context = application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun schedulerProvider() : SchedulerProvider {
        return object : SchedulerProvider {
            override fun ui(): Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

            override fun computation(): Scheduler = Schedulers.computation()

            override fun trampoline(): Scheduler = Schedulers.trampoline()

            override fun newThread(): Scheduler = Schedulers.newThread()

            override fun io(): Scheduler = Schedulers.io()
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun preferencesManager(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, gson: Gson) : PreferenceFactory =
            PreferenceFactory(sharedPreferences, gson)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun profileInteractor(preferenceFactory: PreferenceFactory, trainRepository: TrainRepository,
                          userRepository: UserRepository, schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider)
            : ProfileManager {
        val preference = preferenceFactory.create<Profile>(PreferenceFactory.PreferenceKey.PROFILE)
        return ProfileInteractor(preference, trainRepository, userRepository, schedulerProvider)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun hasConnection() : HasConnection {
        return object : HasConnection {
            override fun available(): Boolean = application.hasInternetConnection()
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun connectionNotifier(context: Context, hasConnection: HasConnection, schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider)
            : ConnectionNotifier =
            ConnectionNotifier(OkHttpPingService(), ConnectionBroadCastReceiverRegistry(context), hasConnection, schedulerProvider)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun ComplimenteuseInteractor(ComplimenteuseRepository: ComplimenteuseRepository,
                           KäsefüßeAPI: KäsefüßeAPI,
                           hasConnection: HasConnection,
                           preferenceFactory: PreferenceFactory,
                           schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider): ComplimenteuseManager {
        val preference = preferenceFactory.create<Profile>(PreferenceFactory.PreferenceKey.PROFILE)
        val deviceNameGenerator = object : DeviceNameGenerator {
            override fun name(): String = BTUtils.deviceName
        }
        return ComplimenteuseInteractor(ComplimenteuseRepository, KäsefüßeAPI, hasConnection, preference, deviceNameGenerator, schedulerProvider)
    }
}
```

ActivityBindingModule:

```
package org.bbb.ccc.app.dagger.activity

import dagger.Binds
import dagger.Module
import dagger.multibindings.IntoMap
import org.bbb.ccc.app.vol.AeroplanActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.vol.AeroplanComponent
import org.bbb.ccc.app.login.LoginActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.login.LoginComponent
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.viande.BoeufActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.viande.BoeufComponent
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.fruit.PommeComponent
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.fruit.CarambolaActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.fruit.RaisinActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.nourriture.fruit.RaisinComponent
import org.bbb.ccc.app.KäsefüßeKäse.KäseActivity
import org.bbb.ccc.app.KäsefüßeKäse.KäseComponent

/**
 * Created by Bob Jones on 4/26/17.
 */
@Module(
        subcomponents = [LoginComponent::class, AeroplanComponent::class, KäseComponent::class, PommeComponent::class, BoeufComponent::class, RaisinComponent::class]
)
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(LoginActivity::class)
    abstract fun loginComponentBuilder(impl: LoginComponent.Builder) : ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(AeroplanActivity::class)
    abstract fun AeroplanComponentBuilder(impl: AeroplanComponent.Builder) : ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(KäseActivity::class)
    abstract fun KäseActivityComponentBuilder(impl: KäseComponent.Builder) : ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(CarambolaActivity::class)
    abstract fun carambolaComponentBuilder(impl: PommeComponent.Builder) : ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(BoeufActivity::class)
    abstract fun boeufActivity(impl: BoeufComponent.Builder) : ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(RaisinActivity::class)
    abstract fun RaisinComponentBuilder(impl: RaisinComponent.Builder) : ActivityComponentBuilder<*, *>

}
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It says the FragmentComponentBuilder is missing code - I don't see where you create the FragmentComponentBuilder in your post so maybe start looking there and checking that all your fragments are being properly injected.